# Windows Server 2012 R2 printer deployment ghost printers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, deployment, network-printer

I have problem with printer deployment in Windows Server 2012 R2, so the problem is when deploy printer with one driver, and then change driver for that printer, i have ghost copies on computers in domain and on server only one printer. Another problem is with paper size, if i set on server, printer preferences A4 size, and on printers itself, on computers on network are still letter size... changed location of server and computers, change to metric, deploy few times nothing help... Does anyone have expirience with this type of problem? Printers I deploy are xerox, lexmark and hp plotter...

Comment: I really don't understand the issue you describe. I guess you're having two issues, but even that is not clear to me. Could you please try to rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can get "ghost printers" if you change your print driver while there is still documents waiting to be printed. To solve this, try delete the print queue and restart the print spooler service.

When changing paper size/orientation etc this has to be done from the "Advanced" tab and "printing defaults" button on the printer properties on the server. if you change it from the "General" tab and Preferences, it will only affect the local user profile.

I guess you are connecting to the shared printer on the server \\server\printername and not creating a local port on the client connecting to the ip address of the printer

Comment: When i changed the driver there are no documents waiting to be printed. I done all of that. Intresting is that i dont have ghost printer on all computers in domain, its like 50-50% situation. In advanced tab i dont have that option, think there is a driver problem. Yes, i connected to the shared printer on server. Any other ideas? The second problem is when i delete printer deployment, on half computer deploy printers are left, cant remove them...

Comment: Make sure you use a print driver designed for server usage and if possible for terminal server environment. If you use a standard desktop print driver you can almost be 100% sure it will give you a loot of problem in a network environment. This kind of drivers should never be certified by Microsoft because all of them is just a huge piece of crap.

Comment: Yes i did use drivers for server. So you when the name of driver “microsoft certified” mean is the best choise. My users uses autocad, adobe and office...